# How many numbers between 1 and 10000 are multiples of 4 or 5 or 7? How many of those numbers are also multiples of 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I think to find the answer of first questions, I would find 
$$
\begin{multline}
 \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{4} \right\rfloor
 + \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{5} \right\rfloor 
 + \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{7} \right\rfloor \\
 − \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{\mathrm{lcm}(4,5)} \right\rfloor 
 - \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{\mathrm{lcm}(5,7)} \right\rfloor 
 - \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{\mathrm{lcm}(4,7)} \right\rfloor 
 - \left\lfloor \frac{10000}{\mathrm{lcm}(4,5,7)} \right\rfloor . 
\end{multline}
$$

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing the second part correctly. Would it just be the answer from the previous questions
$${} + \lfloor 10000/3 \rfloor - \lfloor 10000/\mathrm{lcm}(3,4) \rfloor - \lfloor 10000/\mathrm{lcm}(3,5) \rfloor - \lfloor 10000/\mathrm{lcm}(3,7) \rfloor $$
and so on until I get to the $\mathrm{lcm}(3,4,5,7)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: You did the first part correctly.  The second part, no, that would have been the answer to "How many numbers between 1 and 10000 are multiples of 4 or 5 or 7 or 3" which is different than the question of "How many multiples of 3 between 1 and 10000 are multiples of 4 or 5 or 7?"

Comment: The question that is being asked is the second one that I wrote above.  Written yet another way, "How many numbers between 1 and 10000 are multiples of 12, 15, or 21?"

Comment: The last term, ⌊10000/lcm(4,5,7)⌋, should be added, not subtracted.

Comment: Ah I understand now. So the answer for the first part would be 4857? And to find the second part, I would go through the exact same steps, except I would be finding the multiples of 12, 15, or 21 in the range? Thank you so much!

Comment: I took the liberty to convert  your formulas into the format we use for nicely typesetting mathematics here. You can see how I did it by clicking on "edit", and use the same techniques on later questions.